# how to draw 3D cuboid on mouse drag in deck gl?

Tags: javascript, 3d, deck.gl

i have a point-cloud layer which render point cloud data and on top of that i need to draw a 3D cuboid on drag of mouse.
i tried nebula.gl but it is not working as i expected attaching a screenshot of my desired output[image]

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Yes Using nebula.gl + deck.gl's polygon layer